# Overlay status bar and system button bar in full screen mode

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to write an app with overlay status bar and system button bar like below picture. I tried

```
View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
```

but it when status bar and system button bar appear, they come with two black bars. Can anyone help me?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThURG.jpg)

Comment: try this `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` for <application in manifest.xml

Comment: thank you but it not work as my expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Documentation:**
The figure below illustrates the different "immersive mode" states:
[image]

> **Situation 4 - Sticky flag** This is the UI you see if you use the IMMERSIVE_STICKY flag, and the user swipes to display the system bars. Semi-transparent
>   bars temporarily appear and then hide again. The act of swiping
>   doesn't clear any flags, nor does it trigger your system UI visibility
>   change listeners, because the transient appearance of the system bars
>   isn't considered a UI visibility change.

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html